# How to recover after deleting the symbolic link libc.so.6?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, glibc

In our server the symbolic link to `libc.so.6` has been deleted. Now none of the binaries in the system work. To fix this, I tried:

```
/bin/ln -s /lib/libc-2.11.3.so /lib/libc.so.6
```

which, as expected, gives me:

```
/bin/ln: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: 
    cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried:

```
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  --inhibit-rpath /lib/libc.so.6 \
   --library-path /lib/libc-2.11.3.so \
   /bin/ln -s /lib/libc-2.11.3.so /lib/libc.so.6
```

with the same result. Further unsuccessful attempts include cp, mv, cat.

I'm connected via ssh and I believe I will not be able to open another session after closing this one. Is there a way to fix this system (using bash built-ins perhaps)?

[**edit**] I did:

```
while read line; do echo $line; done < /lib/libc-2.11.3.so > libc.so.6
```

to copy the file and tried with:

```
/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  --inhibit-rpath libc.so.6 --library-path . \
  /bin/ln -s /lib/libc-2.11.3.so /lib/libc.so.6
```

and got:

```
/bin/ln: error while loading shared libraries: ./libc.so.6: ELF file OS ABI invalid
```

Comment: You might use a static binary, e.g. the `sash` statically linked shell (which you would have installed before) which contains a builtin `cp`-like command

Comment: Your `echo` needs a `-nE` or it will add newlines to the output, which you don't want, and may interpret escapes

Comment: copying the files with read/echo does not make it executable...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could simply run `ldconfig`. Most distributions ship this as a static binary.

Comment: Good question. I've been brought up in the old tradition of actually getting a root shell rather than typing sudo every time, so I've never run into that problem (and yes, I accidentally deleted libc.so.6 once)

Comment: @Matt 2015 update: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS provides /sbin/ldconfig

Comment: I'm getting `Can't link /usr/lib/libc.so.6 ...` and `Can't create temporary cache file: Permission denied`. Looks like the command has to be run as root. Any chance of recovery without an open root shell?

Answer (score 13):

This helped in my case (the actual version depends on your library):

```
ldconfig -l -v /lib/libc-2.13.so
```

Comment: This gave me `ldconfig: Cannot lstat /lib/libc-2.13.so: No such file or directory`, I found a file called `libc-2.17.so` but that gives me the same error, so I think the error is referring to `lstat` missing?

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libc-2.17.so ln -s /lib/libc-2.17.so /lib/libc.so.6
```

Note: The actual version depends on your library.

Comment: Thank you!  I (accidentally) hosed an embedded system with no `ldconfig`, but this worked.

Answer (score 5):

Boot using a live cd like Knoppix or whatever and fix the missing link after mounting the disk with the "broken" system out of the running live system.

Comment: thanks, but at this time I'm looking for a way to fix this over my open ssh session :(

Comment: Maybe you have a statically linked binary of perl, python, lua, ...?

Comment: Try to `scp` a static binary like the `sash` shell

Comment: @wollud1969, thanks! I managed to execute cp, ln.. with LD_PRELOAD. Still having problems with sudo though.

Comment: Where comes sudo in the game?

Comment: How about LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libc.so.6 bash ? will open you shell and all commands inside this shell should inherit that setting, i think. or... maybe not sudo. Can you use `sudo su` or just `su` to become root? The new environment will need LD_PRELOAD set again.

Comment: Daniel S you saved my life just now!

Comment: @wollud1969, sorry for revoking the accept but this happened to me again :) and this time I was able to fix the system without physical access via ldconfig

Comment: @perreal did you manage to get around sudo? I cannot link it back without sudo...

Answer (score 4):

Note, for 64 bit:

`LD_PRELOAD=libc-2.13.so ln -s libc-2.13.so libc.so.6`

This worked great for me

If you are not in that directory of course it will be something like:
`LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

Answer (score 3):

If you had done an ls command previously and know what the version of the libc is,

```
ldconfig -l -v /lib64/libc-2.x.so
```

where `x` is your version works. Note that it could be a lib64 or lib depending on your version.

I just did this and it worked.

In short, never delete the link. Bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Ubuntu, ldconfig won't work. Just run:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks you very much for below answer.  It worked well with root ID.
We unlink `libc.so.6` to link with higher version but suddenly after unlink libc.so.6 server become unresponsive.  `ln -s` command was not working.  No other users were able to ssh to server.  But when we ran below command it worked. (with libc version exist on server) server started to behave normally.

Below one is correct command and life saving too....

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libc-2.17.so ln -s /lib/libc-2.17.so /lib/libc.so.6
```

Note: The actual version depends on your library

Answer (score 1):

For others, all those working solutions require you being `root` before you mess up the system.

Because those `lib`, `lib64` directories requires `root` permission to create or update files.

So if you are not `root`, you are done and don't waste time trying. Go boot from another system and repair it.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally deleted the file /lib64/libc.so.6 while trying to upgrade the symbolic link... It was bizarre. None of the commands worked ls, du,cd vim,su, etc

the only thing that saved me was, I was logged in as a root user already
so ran "$ sln /lib64/libc.so-2.12 /lib64/libc.so.6"
which kind of saved my life

please refer to this link it's very very helpful. instead of booting server and
https://www.programmersought.com/article/2176688665/
Just make sure the symbolic link u can linking again is the same as the previous one

recommend trying everything before rebooting etc and don't log out of the bash terminal