# Accidentally deleted symlink libc.so.6 in CentOS 6.4. How to get sudo privilege to re-create it?

Tags: linux, centos

I accidentally deleted the symbol link /lib64/libc.so.6 -> /lib64/libc-2.12.so with

```
$ sudo rm libc.so.6
```

Then I can not use anything including `ls` command. The error appears for any command I type

```
ls: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried

```
$ export LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libc-2.12.so
```

After this I can use `ls` and `ln ...`, but still can not use `sudo ln ...` or `sudo -E ln ...`. I always get this err

```
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It's a remote server so I can not use a live CD. I now have a ssh bash session alive but can not establish new ones. I have sudo privilege, but don't have root password.

So currently my problem is I need to run `sudo sln -s libc-2.12.so libc.so.6` to re-create the symlink `libc.so.6`, but I  can not run `sudo` without `libc.so.6`.

How can I fix it? Thanks~

Comment: @OlegMikheev No, either `$ su` or `$ sudo su`

Comment: Maybe you could try to scp the same version of libc.so.6 from a different machine to yours...

Comment: Boot from a different image (maybe a live CD).  You won't be able to run any command, for all intents and purposes, until you have `libc.so.6` back, so you have to find a way of running an O/S that will allow you to replace the symlink.  You don't have to install the O/S; you just need to run it long enough to get to a point where you can mount the root file system of your normal O/S and fix the symlink.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can not even get sudo privilege to reboot the machine ...

Comment: @rakib yes but not to the files owned by root

Comment: Create a symlink from a folder that your id has access to (e.g. your home folder, or I'd create a ~/bin ) and add that folder to the system $PATH (I'd put it at the front).  That might be enough for it to pick it up enough to run sudo ... Good luck.

Comment: @eric If you can do "sudo chmod 777 /etc/password", then try to manipulate the root user password.

Comment: There's an on-off switch — you'll probably need to use that, along with magical incantations on the keyboard (or an actual CD in the CD drive) to get the system to reboot from a new image. It ain't trivial; I'd not want to have to do it. This should have been migrated to ServerFault or SuperUser by now. You might need to pretend to upgrade your O/S (even though 6.4 is the latest, you might be able to 'upgrade' it again, restoring the library). Removing the symlink that all system executables depend on is a very effective a way of disabling a system.

Comment: Do you have any means to get into single user mode? It'll give you root access if so and hopefully allow you to recreate the symlink.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, but it seems there's no way I can get root now. So have to wait for help. http://serverfault.com/questions/519664/accidentally-deleted-symlink-libc-so-6-in-centos-6-4-how-to-get-sudo-privilege

Comment: same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249547/how-to-recover-after-deleting-the-symbolic-link-libc-so-6

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by using a statically linked version of "ln" that was already in the server's /sbin.

E.g., this restored it for my configuration:
/sbin/sln /lib64/libc-2.5.so /lib64/libc.so.6

Answer (score 1):

A bit embarrassing :) but it happened to me as well on **Ubuntu 12.04.3** (which is not CentOS 6.4 but I thought this could still help maybe).

Because my Ubuntu wouldn't start I used a liveUSB to boot up and then mounted my hard drive and created the symlink (I did have the file itself `libc-2.15.so`) and that did it.

Just a few specific details:

1. I asked a good friend to use his computer for half an hour
2. I Downloaded my exact Ubuntu iso (12.04.3, if you're on;y missing the symlink, it could be any version so much that it can mount drives) from here: [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
3. I made sure his Ubuntu has usb-creator-gtk (`$ sudo apt-get install usb-gtk-creator`, I'm sure Windows has an equivalent usb boot creator)
4. Created the liveUSB using usb-creator-gtk
5. Booted my computer with it (you'll probably need to change your BIOS settings to allow external USB to be booted first)
6. Once I booted from the live USB I figured where my hard drive partition by running the Ubuntu partition tool (the live USB has one) - mine was of type `ext4` and in `/dev/sdb1`
7. I mounted it by doing `$ mkdir /home/ubuntu/mnt` and then `$ sudo mount-t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /home/ubuntu/mnt`
8. I then proceeded to that folder `$ cd /home/ubuntu/mnt`
9. From that location I then created the symlink by `$ sudo ln -s lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

After a reboot I was good.

Hope it helps you (or someone..)

Comment: Something i would like to add: used **fdisk** to locate partition to mount. If you dont have BIOS access like i did - there is a workaround - you can use **grub** to boot USB. Ubuntu: Press 'c' while in grub. List and switch root to USB (in my case it was hd2). If you had only problem with getting to root, its possible to load bash with root rights from grub also. So more or less linuxes are not as safe as ppl think they are :)

Answer (score 0):

I would add some thing more to @wilfo answer as same also happened with me [accidentally deleting lib.so.6 and was getting /sbin/init missing libc.so.6 on boot up] .
After creating liveUSB in windows (using UNetbootin etc [http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/]) or in ubuntu as @wilfo suggested. 
Booting from liveUSB, I selected "experience ubuntu without installing it" and was happy applying wilfo's method until step 6 and then i couldn't find my hard drive partition of type ext3/4. All were nftf/fat/extended stuff.

So i recovered previous ubuntu (the one with missing libc.so...) by following this link 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

make sure to follow all necessary steps and take a backup of your ubuntu partition. 
you can see your previous ubuntu files inside /mnt/boot-sav/wubi1/home
take a backup from here to your windows partations /mnt/boot-sav/sda...
and follow remaining procedure here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair