# Cannot run any commands because I moved the libc.so file

Tags: linux, unix, dynamic-linking

I have a dynamic linker which is `/lib64/libc.so.6`

I stupidly renamed it to `/lib64/libc.so.6.old` and now NO commands work.

I cannot do `ls` or `mv` to rename it back.

I can run `ldconfig` but it says permission denied and I cannot run `sudo` or `su -` What on earth can I do to fix this? I am running Oracle Linux redhat 6.7

Comment: Have you Googled this? Other people have done similar things and fixed it. And posted answers on StackOverflow. For instance, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387297/accidentally-deleted-symlink-libc-so-6-in-centos-6-4-how-to-get-sudo-privilege

Comment: Maybe there is a usable program in /sbin/ or /usr/sbin? Maybe there is a network mount that you can use to invoke a statically linked binary? or maybe just a statically linked shell?

Answer (score 4):

```
 LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libc.so.6.old mv /lib64/libc.so.6.old /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from a recovery/install iso and rename the file back.

If you can't reboot or don't have physical access to the machine you could try to install a compiled version of BusyBox https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#getting_started and use its su and mv commands. Since BusyBox is statically linked it should work without libc.so.

Comment: How would I install something without being able to get onto the machine?

Comment: in this case "just" copy the binary (which can be quite hard without libc.) but the recovery-iso is definitely the easyer way.

Answer (score 0):

Go to single user mode, mount the file system with rw, since you know the location of the renamed file move /lib64/libc.so.6.old /lib64/libc.so.6

Comment: Why should mv work in single user mode if libc.so has been moved?

Answer (score 0):

I would also propose a workaround with a **mount point** as already mentioned by @wildplasser.

You can make majority of command line tools working again if you have a mounted directory on your broken host. If you are lucky to have one then all you need is to upload the libc-x.yz.so (which you can take from another host of from Internet) on the share, rename it there to libc.so.6 and add the mounted directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

If the version x.yz is the same as for the one which you thoughtlessly moved then the commands like ls, cp etc. will work again in the console where you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You should not logout from this console, because *you won't be able to login again*.

! Be aware that *setuid* command line tools won't work (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1029363/832810). Unfortunately "sudo" is one of them, this is why you won't be able to put back easily your long-suffering .so (unless you have a root# console). However it gives you a possibility to save all data and finish all actions before you do some hard restore.

If you managed to do the above-mentioned trick and you have enough time you can try to build a statically linked version of "sudo" as suggested on https://askubuntu.com/a/1030475/832810 (probably even build on another host and copy through NFS) and move the .so back using it.