# How to recover after replacing the symbolic link libc.so.6 with another updated libc.so.6?

Tags: linux

How to recover after replacing the symbolic link libc.so.6 with another updated libc.so.6?

I've checked the below link
[How to recover after deleting the symbolic link libc.so.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249547/how-to-recover-after-deleting-the-symbolic-link-libc-so-6)

The problem is I have updated the file with another libc.so.6

Is there any other ways to get around without knoppix? i can't do rm, cat, mv.. etc only ldconfig but i cant even replace the file because the link is there. how can i remove this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already fallen into such issue without any preparation, well, it's already great chances you can't restore without external rescue boot. For future experiments, you can use one of the following preparations:

- Start `mc` (Midnight Commander) or another complex shell-like tool with embedded filesystem actions implementation, in a separate terminal.
- Create "rescue" tool set (like one in FreeBSD under /rescue).
- Start a `REPL` tool of any script language (Python, Ruby, etc.); maybe some imports (like `sys`, `os`, `os.path` in Python) shall be called before a dangerous step.

(For all such actions, backup copy of critical system paths before experiments is a good manner.)

But some minor actions can be done in a bare shell without working libc. In most interactive shells like `bash`, there are some useful builtins, so you can:

- `echo *`, `echo /lib/*` instead of `ls`
- `echo -n >$file` to make it empty; for `ldconfig`, this effectively removes it from libraries because ldconfig lists only correctly recognized libraries in its cache;
- if `printf` is shell builtin (as for modern `bash`), you can create any binary using it and shell redirection; this is very slowly and typo prone but still can be a chance.

Next, setting LD_PRELOAD for a proper libc version before each external command invocation allows replacing any library with another one; e.g. `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libc-2.11.3.so ls` will run `ls` with all external symbols found in /lib/libc-2.11.3.so have overridden their namesakes from the one you have installed. (Don't try use `env` before export specification! It will fail with broken libc and isn't needed for any B-group shell like `bash`.) Exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH with a backup copy of /lib, /usr/lib allows to get out from most problems with broken main library directories. (NB this method was described in the question you linked to. Did you really try it?)

I hope another hacker methods can be added to this list.

P.S. Shouldn't this question be moved to ServerFault?

Comment: in the end i used knoppix. thanks anyway!